# Google Doc's (Spreadsheet) get Revision Id

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I'm testing this page:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/get#try-it

I can't find the revision id and when i try put something like i think is the revision id, an error is displayed saying: *"message": "Revision not found: "*

How i can find the revision id of the file (i'm trying for Spreadsheet)?

Later i'll try to use (in java):

```
RevisionList revisions = service.revisions().list(fileId).execute();
return revisions.getItems();
```

But for now i need to do manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine. You need some correct file id and revision id.

For eg -

File Id = `0Vs336aBx5r3MdHJz1TZaCi1kb0JsOExoSHJDMWFZVUE` 
Revision Id = `13723331213000`

Steps -

1. Get a valid File Id from here. In try it out - maxResults = 5
   https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list 
   From the json reply select any file id.
2. Get all the revisions for this file - https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/list 
    Try it out - fieldId = enter the File Id copied from above step. 
   From the json reply select any revision id
3. Now use the File Id and Revision Id here - https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/get#try-it